# sf.touchscreen.js causing unintentional hover effect on iOS

Tags: 7, javascript, navigation

I was hoping someone could help me isolate and extract the snippet responsible for triggering the :hover/:focus css, from this Superfish plugin js.

Basically when ‘long’ touching any link on the page, on the mobile, the CSS is triggered, and only a normal short tap activates the link. In my case, it’s what I want.

Unfortunately, I need a SF menu active on the page somewhere, with sf.touchscreen plug-in active. Smallscreen and hoverintent can be turned off and it still works, so I’m very confident it’s leaching from sf.touchscreen, but only if the active menu contains items.

At the moment I do not need superfish for all menus, but I like the effect. I would like to add the snippet extracted and add it to my Drupal behaviours.js to be always on.

Anyone know how to do this?
I tried adding it to my .info, but I don’t know how to activate it without a menu.

7.x-1.9+33-dev
the plugin code:

```
(function($){
  $.fn.sftouchscreen = function(options){
    options = $.extend({
      mode: 'inactive',
      breakpoint: 768,
      breakpointUnit: 'px',
      useragent: '',
      behaviour: 2,
      disableHover: false 
    }, options);

    function activate(menu){
      var eventHandler = (('ontouchstart' in window) || (window.DocumentTouch && document instanceof DocumentTouch)) ? ['click touchstart','mouseup touchend'] : ['click','mouseup'];
      // Select hyperlinks from parent menu items.
      menu.find('li:has(ul)').children('a,span.nolink').each(function(){
        var item = $(this),
        parent = item.closest('li');
        if (options.disableHover){
          parent.unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');
        }
        if (options.behaviour == 2){
          if (parent.children('a.menuparent,span.nolink.menuparent').length > 0 && parent.children('ul').children('.sf-clone-parent').length == 0){
            var
            // Cloning the hyperlink of the parent menu item.
            cloneLink = parent.children('a.menuparent,span.nolink.menuparent').clone(),
            // Wrapping the hyerplinks in <li>.
            cloneLink = $('<li class="sf-clone-parent" />').html(cloneLink);
            // Removing unnecessary stuff.
            cloneLink.find('.sf-sub-indicator').remove(),
            // Adding a helper class and attaching them to the sub-menus.
            parent.children('ul').addClass('sf-has-clone-parent').prepend(cloneLink);
          }
        }
        // No .toggle() here as it's not possible to reset it.
        item.bind(eventHandler[0], function(event){
          // Already clicked?
          if (item.hasClass('sf-clicked')){
            // Depending on the preferred behaviour, either proceed to the URL.
            if (options.behaviour == 0){
              window.location = item.attr('href');
            }
            // or collapse the sub-menu.
            else if (options.behaviour == 1 || options.behaviour == 2){
              event.preventDefault();
              item.removeClass('sf-clicked');
              parent.hideSuperfishUl().find('a,span.nolink').removeClass('sf-clicked');
            }
          }
          // Prevent the default action otherwise.
          else {
            event.preventDefault();
            item.addClass('sf-clicked');
            parent.showSuperfishUl().siblings('li:has(ul)').hideSuperfishUl().find('.sf-clicked').removeClass('sf-clicked');
          }
        });
      });

      $(document).bind(eventHandler[1], function(event){
        if (menu.not(event.target) && menu.has(event.target).length === 0){
          menu.find('.sf-clicked').removeClass('sf-clicked');
          menu.find('li:has(ul)').hideSuperfishUl();
        }
      });
    }
    // Return original object to support chaining.
    // This is not necessary actually because of the way the module uses these plugins.
    for (var b = 0; b < this.length; b++) {
      var menu = $(this).eq(b),
      mode = options.mode;
      // The rest is crystal clear, isn't it? :)
      if (mode == 'always_active'){
        activate(menu);
      }
      else if (mode == 'window_width'){
        var breakpoint = (options.breakpointUnit == 'em') ? (options.breakpoint * parseFloat($('body').css('font-size'))) : options.breakpoint,
        windowWidth = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth,
        timer;
        if ((typeof Modernizr === 'undefined' || typeof Modernizr.mq !== 'function') && windowWidth < breakpoint){
          activate(menu);
        }
        else if (typeof Modernizr !== 'undefined' && typeof Modernizr.mq === 'function' && Modernizr.mq('(max-width:' + (breakpoint - 1) + 'px)')) {
          activate(menu);
        }
        $(window).resize(function(){
          clearTimeout(timer);
          timer = setTimeout(function(){
            var windowWidth = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
            if ((typeof Modernizr === 'undefined' || typeof Modernizr.mq !== 'function') && windowWidth < breakpoint){
              activate(menu);
            }
            else if (typeof Modernizr !== 'undefined' && typeof Modernizr.mq === 'function' && Modernizr.mq('(max-width:' + (breakpoint - 1) + 'px)')) {
              activate(menu);
            }
          }, 50);
        });
      }
      else if (mode == 'useragent_custom'){
        if (options.useragent != ''){
          var ua = RegExp(options.useragent, 'i');
          if (navigator.userAgent.match(ua)){
            activate(menu);
          }
        }
      }
      else if (mode == 'useragent_predefined' && navigator.userAgent.match(/(android|bb\d+|meego)|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i)){
        activate(menu);
      }
    }
    return this;
  }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: If you're using a custom theme, perhaps it's easier to just drop it in your scripts.js file and add that to the theme .info file - instructions here.
https://www.drupal.org/node/304255

Comment: that's what I mean by behaviour.js (that's my scripts file) and adding it to .info as per my last sentence. These are the easy bits and not the issue.
I'm trying to add the key part of the code sample in such a way that it does not require an active menu to run.

Comment: I'm assuming you have linked the plugin via your theme .info and it's being included on every page? Not sure what you mean by "activate it without a menu". Are you saying you don't know how to apply the plugin to the DOM? If you're wanting to trigger the sf plugin selectively, add the necessary js selector in your scripts.js file, and include that as well as the plugin file using your theme.info. I'm not understanding what this has to do with Drupal behaviors. This sounds more like a js question than a Drupal question.